# What is the difference between vi is hashed to (<path>) and vim is <path>?

Tags: bash, cygwin, mintty

Can anybody please explain what is the difference between vi is hashed to () and vim is . I am not much familiar with mintty and I don't wanna guess about what is hashed and what is the is operator in mintty. Please help guys!!
[image: bet]
[image]
The macro I have defined isn't working for mintty, I want to make it work for minnty to(as its working with cmd well).

Comment: It means that the location of vi utility is cached, and next time you invoke it, the shell will first try the cached pathname before searching it in paths listed in PATH variable. If you run `hash vim` and then `type vim`, you'll see *vim is hashed ...*.

Comment: @SahilRajput : Please don't ask two questions in once. First you ask about the interpretation of the output of the _type_  command (which, BTW, does not belong to SO, but maybe to [superuser](https://superuser.com/)), and the question is about the definition of _vim_  macros, which is also not really a programming question, and would require the _vim_ tag.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.
from comments on question.
It means that the location of vi utility is cached, and next time you invoke it, the shell will first try the cached pathname before searching it in paths listed in PATH variable. If you run hash vim and then type vim, you'll see vim is hashed .... – oguz ismail 30 mins ago
[image]